# Registered conversion for Entity Framework Core in C# is not called when querying with Contains? Any workaround?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, microsoft.data.sqlite

I am trying to figure out why the conversions defined for my `SqliteDbContext`  below are not considered when a `Contains` is necessary in a request:

```cs
public static class FSharpOptionExtensions
{
    public static T DefaultFromOption<T>(this FSharpOption<T> option)
        where T : IEquatable<T> =>
        (FSharpOption<T>.get_IsNone(option)
            ? default
            : option.Value)!;

    public static FSharpOption<T> ToOption<T>(this T source)
        where T : IEquatable<T> =>
        source.Equals(default)
            ? FSharpOption<T>.None
            : FSharpOption<T>.Some(source);
}

public class SqliteDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SqliteRecord>? Records { get; set; }

    public SqliteDbContext() // : base()
    {
    }

    public SqliteDbContext(DbContextOptions<SqliteDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var faker = new Faker();
        var recordCount = faker.Random.Int(500, 1000);
        var records = Enumerable
            .Range(1, recordCount)
            .Select(index => new SqliteRecord
            {
                Id = index,
                Integer = faker.Random.Long(),
                Real = faker.Random.Double(),
                NullableText = faker.Name.FullName().OrNull(faker, .2f),
                NonNullableText = faker.Commerce.Product(),
                FSharpOptionText = FSharpOption<string>.Some(faker.Vehicle.Manufacturer())
                    .OrDefault(faker, 0.5f, FSharpOption<string>.None)
            });

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<SqliteRecord>()
            .Property(x => x.FSharpOptionText)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<FSharpOption<string>?, string>(
                option => option!.DefaultFromOption(),
                value => value.ToOption()));

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<SqliteRecord>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<SqliteRecord>()
            .ToTable("Records")
            .HasData(records);
    }
}
```

```cs
var records = await _dbContext.Records.Select(x => new
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Integer = x.Integer,
    Real = x.Real,
    NullableText = x.NullableText,
    NonNullableText = x.NonNullableText,
    FSharpOptionText = x.FSharpOptionText!.DefaultFromOption()
}).Where(s =>
    s.NullableText!.ToLower().Contains("d") ||
    s.NonNullableText!.ToLower().Contains("d") ||
    s.FSharpOptionText.ToLower().Contains("d")
).ToListAsync();
```

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(s => s.NullableText.ToLower().Contains("d") || s.NonNullableText.ToLo
> wer().Contains("d") || s.FSharpOptionText
> .DefaultFromOption().ToLower().Contains("d"))' could not be translated.
>
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumer
> able(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=
> 2101038 for more information.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVi
> sitor.g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated,
> <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVi
> sitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visi
> tor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVi
> sitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visi
> tor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExe
> cutor[TResult](Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expre
> ssion query, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCor
> e[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayCla
> ss12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQu eryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQu
> ery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TR esult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAs ync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnu
> merator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetA syncEnumerator() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsy nc[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

It doesn't make much sense to me since [the conversion is supposed to be applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions):

> Value converters allow property values to be converted when reading from or writing to the database. This conversion can be from one value to another of the same type (for example, encrypting strings) or from a value of one type to a value of another type (for example, converting enum values to and from strings in the database.)

Unless "reading" doesn't apply when "querying" and if that's really the case, wondering if there is any workaround out there? Any mechanism to extend how the expression is parsed?

---

Btw the query below works just fine:

```cs
var records = await _dbContext.Records.Select(x => new
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Integer = x.Integer,
    Real = x.Real,
    NullableText = x.NullableText,
    NonNullableText = x.NonNullableText,
    FSharpOptionText = x.FSharpOptionText!.DefaultFromOption()
}).Where(x => x.Id == 1).ToListAsync();
```

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4 initialized 'SqliteDbContext
' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeou
t='30']
      SELECT "r"."Id", "r"."Integer", "r"."Real", "r"."NullableText", "r"."NonNu
llableText", "r"."FSharpOptionText"
      FROM "Records" AS "r"
      WHERE "r"."Id" = 1
```

Comment: Why are you test a nullable and non nullable for "d"? I would try : .Where(s => (s != null) && (s.NonNullableText!.ToLower().Contains("d") ||
    s.FSharpOptionText.ToLower().Contains("d")))

Comment: public DbSet<SqliteRecord>? Records { get; set; } . Make it non nullable .you call SqliteRecord as non nullable .so remove ? and make public DbSet<SqliteRecord> Records { get; set; }

Comment: @LDS it doesn't really address the question, right?

Comment: @jdweng .Where(s => (s != null) && (s.NonNullableText!.ToLower().Contains("d") || s.FSharpOptionText.ToLower().Contains("d"))) doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean you get a compiler error, or you get nothing back, or you get an exception?

Comment: Exception basically stating that the expression cannot be converted to sql statements.